# Getting current position of one of the multiple objects in a figure?

Tags: arrays, user-interface, matlab, position

I wrote a script that returns several text boxes in a figure. The text boxes are moveable (I can drag and drop them), and their positions are predetermined by the data in an input matrix (the data from the input matrix is applied to the respective positions of the boxes by nested for loop). I want to create a matrix which is initially a copy of the input matrix, but is UPDATED as I change the positions of the boxes by dragging them around. How would I update their positions? Here's the entire script

```
function drag_drop=drag_drop(tsinput,infoinput)
[x,~]=size(tsinput);
dragging = [];
orPos = [];
fig = figure('Name','Docker Tool','WindowButtonUpFcn',@dropObject,...
'units','centimeters','WindowButtonMotionFcn',@moveObject,...
'OuterPosition',[0 0 25 30]);
% Setting variables to zero for the loop
plat_qty=0;
time_qty=0;
k=0;
a=0; 
% Start loop
z=1:2
    for idx=1:x
        if tsinput(idx,4)==1
            color='red';
        else
            color='blue';
        end
        a=tsinput(idx,z);
       b=a/100;
        c=floor(b); % hours
        d=c*100;
        e=a-d; % minutes
        time=c*60+e; % time quantity to be used in 'position'
        time_qty=time/15;
        plat_qty=tsinput(idx,3)*2;
        box=annotation('textbox','units','centimeters','position',...
        [time_qty plat_qty 1.5 1.5],'String',infoinput(idx,z),...
        'ButtonDownFcn',@dragObject,'BackgroundColor',color); 
        % need to new=get(box,'Position'), fill out matrix OUT of loop
    end
    fillmenu=uicontextmenu;
    hcb1 = 'set(gco, ''BackgroundColor'', ''red'')';
    hcb2 = 'set(gco, ''BackgroundColor'', ''blue'')';
    item1 = uimenu(fillmenu, 'Label', 'Train Full', 'Callback', hcb1);
    item2 = uimenu(fillmenu, 'Label', 'Train Empty', 'Callback', hcb2);
    hbox=findall(fig,'Type','hggroup');
    for jdx=1:x
        set(hbox(jdx),'uicontextmenu',fillmenu);
    end
end
new_arr=tsinput;

function dragObject(hObject,eventdata)
dragging = hObject;
orPos = get(gcf,'CurrentPoint');
end

function dropObject(hObject,eventdata,box)
if ~isempty(dragging)
    newPos = get(gcf,'CurrentPoint');
    posDiff = newPos - orPos;
    set(dragging,'Position',get(dragging,'Position') + ...
    [posDiff(1:2) 0 0]);
    dragging = [];
end
end

function moveObject(hObject,eventdata)
if ~isempty(dragging)
newPos = get(gcf,'CurrentPoint');
posDiff = newPos - orPos;
orPos = newPos;
set(dragging,'Position',get(dragging,'Position') + [posDiff(1:2) 0 0]);
end
end
end

% Testing purpose input matrices:
% tsinput=[0345 0405 1 1 ; 0230 0300 2 0; 0540 0635 3 1; 0745 0800 4 1]
% infoinput={'AJ35 NOT' 'KL21 MAN' 'XPRES'; 'ZW31 MAN' 'KM37 NEW' 'VISTA';
% 'BC38 BIR' 'QU54 LON' 'XPRES'; 'XZ89 LEC' 'DE34 MSF' 'DERP'}
```

Comment: How exactly do you update the position of the text boxes?

Comment: @Itamar Katz : Since the property of the textboxes 'Position' consists of 4 elements [x y width height], the new x and y is what I aim to 'update' or record in a duplicate of the matrix which previously dictated where the boxes should go. I'd aim to do that by something like `get(gco,'Position)`

Comment: You wrote `I change the positions of the boxes by dragging them around`, so in whatever callback in which you are updating the boxes' position, you can as well update the matrix, don't you? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @Itamar Katz : That is true - I've been trying to do that for a short while now. I have three main functions that enable movement, and these compare previous position with position the object's being dragged to. I now need to find the best way to extract that information from these functions. You understood the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand your problem in 100%. If you can put some code and tell what you tried so far, it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (and please post some code if I'm not), then all you need is indeed a set/get combination.

If `boxHandle` is a handle to the text-box object, then you get its current position by:

```
pos = get (boxHandle, 'position')
```

where `pos` is the output array of [x, y, width, height].
In order to set to a new position, you use:

```
set (boxHandle, 'position', newPos)
```

where `newPos` is the array of desired position (with the same structure as `pos`).

**EDIT**

Regarding to updating your matrix, since you have the handle of the object you move, you actually DO have access to the specific text box.

When you create each text box, set a property called 'UserData' with the associated indices of `tsinput` used for that box. In your nested for loop add this

```
set (box, 'UserData', [idx, z]);
```

after the box is created, and in your `moveObject` callback get the data by

```
udata = get(dragging,'UserData');
```

Then `udata` contains the indices of the elements you want to update.

Comment: My main problem is the fact that the functions enabling movement deal with 'current' objects, which means the only data I can get is in form of numbers x and y indicating position but unattached to any specific text box. I'll try to post most of the script right now

Comment: Katz : Yes, that makes sense. I was thinking in the opposite direction. Thanks for the answer.